# React set state without new variable mutation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a state variable an array and data is being pulled from db which has 2 columns id and bookName

If something changes in this state variable, I re-assign the list so that the UI will update. Due to this, the original list is now changed which I dont want

One possible solution I thought is to define another temp state variable and keep changing this temp state variable based on original list

But my question is why to create a duplicate data every time? If I have 10 lists then I will have 10 more duplicates causing total 20 items.

Experts - could you please help with the optimized solution?

Comment: `If something changes in this state variable` what kind of change ? `I re-assign the list` what do you mean by re-assign ?

Comment: Like addition of a book from UI or deletion of a book from UI something like that which does not involves changes to be fetched again from db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding another duplicate state variable to track the original data and another state variable to track the changes I am doing. If someone still has some answers, please share it....